# Difference between OS X md5 and gnu md5sum

Tags: hash, macos, md5

I have installed the "md5sum" utility on my Mac and there was also a "md5" binary pre-installed in /sbin.
My problem and question is this: "Isn't MD5 a standard algorithm?"
Because I get different hashes for a string using these utilities
Are there any differences in these utilities' implementations?
Example:

```
Mehdi-MacBook-Pro:~ mehdi$ md5 -s Hello
MD5 ("Hello") = 8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7

Mehdi-MacBook-Pro:~ mehdi$ echo Hello | md5sum
09f7e02f1290be211da707a266f153b3  -
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, echo leaves a trailing newline. So you need to do:

```
echo -n Hello | md5sum

8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7
```

Comment: Related [post here](http://labs.sasslantis.ee/2011/04/md5sum-vs-md5-different-algorithms/)

Answer (score 7):

Consider this:

```
$ echo Hello | md5sum 
09f7e02f1290be211da707a266f153b3  -
$ echo -n Hello | md5sum
8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7  -
```

In the first case, you hash *six* bytes, for 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and a newline character (0x0A). In the second, you don't include the newline character, which mimics what OS X `md5` utility does with the argument `-s`.

Comment: +1. You might mention that this problem bites a lot of people: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293755/is-unix-md5-different-to-pythons-hashlib-md5), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169605/why-phps-md5-is-different-from-openssls-md5), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604892/is-the-md5sum-linux-command-working-right), etc.

Answer (score 1):

`md5` on the Mac is not 100% compatible with `md5sum`.

The algorithm is, as you correctly say, standardised, but the usage is not.

`md5` on the Mac, for example, does not accept the `--check` option. `md5sum` on the Mac aliases to `md5 -r`, which can lead to unexpected behaviour.

[MacOS `md5`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/md5/)

[Linux `md5sum`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html)